# Can I use htmlentities() in an SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, html-entities

Much thanks for the discussion my original question generated.  I took Jay's suggestion to use bind_param(), but there is something I don't understand about it that may be giving me the Server Error: "The website encountered an error while retrieving...".  I don't know what the parameter 'sssd' that came with the example means.

Any suggestions as to what is generating the Server Error are much appreciated.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('my-database-address', 'my-username', 'my-password', 'my-database-name');
f (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit(); }

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO volunteers VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $first_name, $last_name, $street_address, $apt_unit, $city, $zip, 
$email, $phone, $planning, $signatures, $canvassing, $phone_bank, $media, $press_releases,
$volunteer_coordinator, $speaker, $house_parties, $web_page, $other, $skills, $organizations);

$first_name = '$_POST[first_name]'; $last_name = '$_POST[last_name]'; $street_address = '$_POST[street_address]';
$apt_unit = '$_POST[apt_unit]'; $city = '$_POST[city]'; $zip = '$_POST[zip]'; $email = '$_POST[email]';
$phone = '$_POST[phone]'; $planning = '$_POST[planning]'; $signatures = '$_POST[signatures]'; 
$canvassing = '$_POST[canvassing]'; $phone_bank = '$_POST[phone_bank]'; $media = '$_POST[media]'; 
$press_releases = '$_POST[press_releases]'; $volunteer_coordinator = '$_POST[volunteer_coordinator]'; 
$speaker = '$_POST[speaker]'; $house_parties = '$_POST[house_parties]'; $web_page = '$_POST[web_page]'; 
$other = '$_POST[other]'; $skills = '$_POST[skills]'; $organizations = '$_POST[organizations]';

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

echo "<br /><br />";
echo "<div class='center-col-wrap'>";
echo "Your information has been received.";
echo "<br /><br />";
echo "Thank you for volunteering!"; echo "<br />";
echo "Your help in this effort to bring greater democracy to Oakland"; echo "<br />";
echo "will go a long way to create a healthy and informed community."; echo "<br />";
echo "<br /><br />";
echo "<a href='http://communitydemocracyproject.org/'>Return to CDP Home Page.</a>";
echo "</div>";

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

MY ORIGINAL QUESTION IS BELOW:

I didn't know if this would work or not.  It does not  So how can I use `htmlentities()` here?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO volunteers (first_name, last_name, street_address, apt_unit, city, zip, email, phone,
planning, signatures, canvassing, phone_bank, media, press_releases, volunteer_coordinator, speaker, 
house_parties, web_page, other, skills, organizations)
VALUES
('htmlentities($_POST[first_name])','htmlentities($_POST[last_name])','htmlentities($_POST[street_address])',
'htmlentities($_POST[apt_unit])','htmlentities($_POST[city])','htmlentities($_POST[zip])',
'htmlentities($_POST[email])','htmlentities($_POST[phone])','$_POST[planning]','$_POST[signatures]','$_POST[canvassing]','$_POST[phone_bank]',
'$_POST[media]','$_POST[press_releases]','$_POST[volunteer_coordinator]','$_POST[speaker]',
'$_POST[house_parties]','$_POST[web_page]','$_POST[other]','htmlentities($_POST[skills])','htmlentities($_POST[organizations])')";
```

Comment: Answered your second question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Theodore said, **never** use `htmlentities()` for "escaping" something you want to put in your DB.

I strongly recommend to use prepared statements when anything that (could) come from outside (the user) is stored in a database.

Prepared statements are really easy to use.

If you use PDO to access you database help can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).
As you can see the `bindParam()` method is used to assign any value to a placeholder in the query.

If you use mysqli you can find the docs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).
The syntax of `bind_param()` is slightly different since the placeholders don't have names (order matters) and first argument is a string that determines what type the arguments have ("s" for string, "i" for integer and so on).

Using prepared statements has several positive effects. First of all it automatically masks the data that is provided in the `bindParam()`/`bind_param()` method and is the best way to close the [SQL injection attack vector](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) and it even optimizes the performance of your queries by storing the execution plan in the database (this has a little overhead but if you execute a query twice it pays off double).

PS: `htmlentities()` should only be used if you want to display some HTML as raw text to your users (code listings for instance).

PPS: Don't use `real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL injection since it's not safe ([supeskt.org](http://www.suspekt.org/2008/09/18/slides-from-my-lesser-known-security-problems-in-php-applications-talk-at-zendcon/))

## Update

First of all, for a follow up you should ask a new question. People don't read questions that are already marked as answered and by opening new questions you give kind people an opportunity to get some reward. :)

Nevertheless, the first argument "sssd" tells the database provider that you are passing four arguments, three of type string and a fourth of type double (in the example in the docs three strings and one double are bound ("DEU", "Bavarian", "F" and 11.2)). This is obviously not the case here, you are actually passing (binding) 21 values.

Depending of the type that the columns in your `volunteers` table have you need to pass a string of 21 characters as the first argument.
There are four possible chars that can be used to determine the type:

- i for integer
- d for double (floating point numbers)
- s for string
- b for boolean

All you have to do is to check what types you DB columns have. You will see that the types in the database have different names (like varchar, float etc.). If you google for this names you will find out that they are similar to string, integer, double and boolean. So you have to choose the best matching type depending on the column type (string ≆ varchar, double ≆ float, string ≆ tinytext, string ≆ date/datetime etc. pp.) and you should ensure that the values (your $_POST variables) actually match the type you defined.

Assuming that all your columns are of an text like type like varchar, the first argument would look like 'sssssssssssssssssssss' (21 times s) or 'ssssssssssssssissssss' if the column that takes the volunteer_cordinator is of type int (just for instance).

After you have done this you should double check if `f (mysqli_connect_errno())` is a copy&paste related mistake or if you have actually missed the `i` in your code (should be `if (mysqli_connect_errno())`).

If you have checked that you should consider to write `$_POST['xyz']` instead of `'$_POST[xyz]'`, it will help you, really (`'` marks the start/end of a string and *xyz* is in fact the string here).

If you still encounter errors enable more detailed error information by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file (you should remove this for security reasons when your site goes live) and ask a **new** question.

### Update 2

Double check your MySQL connection string (the arguments you pass in the `mysql()` method). Are you sure that your password starts with an @ and ends with a full stop? By the way, you shouldn't post passwords etc. in the public.

Ensure that you server supports the mysqli methods by running a script containing only

```
<?php
// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();
?>
```

and check the output for something like this:[image: MySQLi enabled]

Comment: WOW, you are making a very big mistake in your very first sentence. Never escape a query to your DB with htmlentities? PDO is just against SQL injection, what about XSS? I think your answer is misleading people, because they will think PDO will also protect them against XSS attacks. You still have to sanitize your output ( I also prefer sanitizing your input, but thats up to you)

Comment: In bind_param, b is blob, not boolean. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 8):

You ***never*** want to use `htmlentities()` on data that's going to be inserted into the database!

## NEVER!

Only use it when you are outputting data *to a web page*.

Otherwise, if you ever want to do anything with that data, ever, that's not directly to a web browser (think, sending emails, or counting words, or outputting to CSV, what have you), you'll quickly realize your error.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question exactly as you wanted, you'll need to exit out of your string:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO volunteers (...) VALUES    
('".htmlentities($_POST['first_name'])."','".htmlentities($_POST['last_name'])'." ...
```

(But please, as Theodore clearly says, don't do this. It's bad. Really, don't do it. Please!)

I think you're trying to escape your input/output. The best way to do is is firstly to stop SQL injection, use your favourite DB escaping method. I'm just using this as an example, you might have a better setup than this short example code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO volunteers (...) VALUES    
('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['first_name'])."','".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['last_name'])'." ...
```

And then when you output, escape using htmlentities:

```
echo htmlentities($output->first_name);
```

Comment: Clair, it's nice to help, and all, but should we really encourage bad behaviors by showing the patient how to in-effect shoot themselves?

Comment: You mean by giving the direct answer? Yes, I think you're probably right there. I've edited my answer to make it clearer that this is bad, but I'll happily remove that example completely if you prefer?

Comment: Hah! No, I'm still genuinely curious as to where to draw the line. I see horrendous stuff on the codereview site all the time and I struggle between telling them what I think is absolutely best (start over, so future devs won't **kill** them) or give them the 30 sec answer.

Comment: I'd like to register an addendum to clair's answer... When I find myself doing stuff with a lot of variables, I invariably use sprintf(), as it greatly aids in readability. Try this: `$string = sprintf("My VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", $val1, $val2, $val3);`

Comment: I'm new to this whole thing so I'm still learning the best way to answer - I always like to know too much so I guess I'm saying too much, even if it will make other people hate me :)  The feedback's appreciated about it!